# IQueryable extension method which becomes an expression

Tags: c#, expression, iqueryable

I'm writing an `IQueryable` implementation for an existing tool. One of the very common features of this tool is a query resembling Exists at the database. In order to support this, I want to extend `IQueryable` with a method such as the following:

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereExists<T, U>(
    this IQueryable<T> Current,
    IQueryable<U> Other,
    Func<T, Field> CurrentSelector) where U : Entity
    {
        return WhereExists(Current, Other, x => x.ID, CurrentSelector);
    }

public static IQueryable<T> WhereExists<T, U>(
    this IQueryable<T> Current,
    IQueryable<U> Other,
    Func<U, Field> RemoteSelector, 
    Func<T, Field> CurrentSelector) where  U : Entity
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException(
            "This method is only implemented for db-backed queries.");
    }
```

The presence of the extension method allows me to get past the compiler, the real functionality will be in the expression visitor.

The catch is that I'd like this to show up in the Expression, but it's running through to the extension method. Are there restrictions which must be followed to get this into the expression (such as with .Where, etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look how the .NET framework does it:

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> Where<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate)
{
    return source.Provider.CreateQuery<TSource>(
       Expression.Call(null, ((MethodInfo) MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()).MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { typeof(TSource) }), new Expression[] { source.Expression, Expression.Quote(predicate) }));
}
```

They package up the parameters into a call expression.

I recommend that you stick to the default `Queryable` methods as much as possible so that you don't have to do much of this trick.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I feel comfortable making my own decisions in this area. Good answer otherwise.

Comment: Sure. Did this answer your question? To me it seems that it does. Your comment left me wondering.

Comment: I cannot accept the answer for 5 more minutes. Yes, thank you. I should have thought to look at the implementation. I was assuming the compiler had some sort of build in support for converting these into expressions, and hadn't realised it was as simple as dispatching to the provider. Thanks again.

Comment: I have implemented a LINQ provider myself and I had the same issue. Note, that sometimes your extension will *not* be called: `items.Where(x => x.SomeCollection.Any(LAMBDA))`. Here, whatever happens inside of `Any` will not be called because it is packed up as an expression. So you can't rely on the call. Therefore, you actual implementation should produce the same expression that the compiler would. This is a design problem in LINQ.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful- I've wondered about this. I've made a few of these before but this one's a bit more comprehensive. I want to package in support for this WhereExists to increase the level of adoption for existing developers, who are familiar with writing queries using that technique.